# Bootstrap select library throws error when trying to increase size of enumdropdownlistfor element

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-select

I have a boostrap select applied to a enumdropdownfor razor element

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, new { @class = "form-control selectpicker" })
```

If I try to increase the element by either of these two methods below the bootstrap select library throws an error.

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('setStyle', 'input-lg', 'add'); //throws error
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('setStyle', 'btn-lg', 'add'); // throws error
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Here is the rendered html

```html
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control input-lg">
  <button title="Female" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default input-lg" aria-expanded="false" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="Gender"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Female</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu open" style="overflow: hidden; min-height: 0px; max-height: 415.19px;">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu" style="-ms-overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: 403.19px;">
      <li data-original-index="0"><a tabindex="0" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">Male</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="selected" data-original-index="1"><a tabindex="0" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">Female</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. it seems to work fine with a dropdownlistfor, but not a enumdropdownlistfor